# Using Direwolf with multiple radios?

Tags: packet, direwolf, ax.25

I'd like to play around with ax.25 connections.  It seems that if I have more than one radio (operating on different frequencies) that I would want to have multiple ax.25 interfaces.  Direwolf creates a `/tmp/kisstnc` symlink to the KISS pty device, and this path is hardcoded.  This means you can only run a single instance of Direwolf providing a KISS pty interface...and since `kissattach` seems to only work with character devices, this would seem to limit a system to a single ax.25 interface when using direwolf.

If I want to run multiple direwolf-controlled ax.25 interfaces, what are my options?  Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there a way to attach an ax.25 interface to Direwolf's KISS network port rather than using the pty device?

Comment: My first instinct would be to compile a separate direwolf binary that used a different filename (or let you pass a filename in). Then you could run the two instances simultaneously talking to different sound cards. Another option might be to chroot so each direwolf ran its own /tmp - then you could refer to /foo/bar/tmp/kisstnc from outside of the chroot jail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've put together something that is conceptually similar to @user3486184's comment, but without actually using `chroot`. I'm taking advantage of SystemD to manage both direwolf and the subsequent kissattach command necessary to activate an ax.25 interface.

I created the following [Systemd template unit](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/) and installed it
into `/etc/systemd/system/direwolf@.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Direwolf %I soundcard modem

[Service]
Type=simple

PrivateTmp=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/direwolf -t 0 -p -c /etc/direwolf/%i.conf -q h -q d

# Relocate /tmp/kisstnc symlink to /run/direwolf/<instance name>.
ExecStartPost=/bin/timeout 10 /bin/sh -c 'while ! test -c /tmp/kisstnc; do sleep 1; done; cp -a /tmp/kisstnc /run/direwolf/%i'

# Clean up symlink on exit.
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /run/direwolf/%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

A "template unit" allows you to start multiple distinct instances of a
service using the same unit file.  To start a template unit, you run
`systemctl unitname@instancename`, and the value of `instancename` is
available to you in the unit as `%i`.  So with the example above, I
could run:

```
systemctl start direwolf@uhf
```

Or:

```
systemctl start direwolf@vhf
```

Etc.  This will start up Direwolf pointing at a configuration named
after the instance; in other words, given the latter example, this
would run:

```
/usr/bin/direwolf -t 0 -p -c /etc/direwolf/vhf.conf -q h -q d
```

The unit makes use of the `PrivateTmp` directive, which when set means
that each service gets its own `/tmp` directory that is not shared
with anything else.  This allows each Direwolf instance to create it's
own `/tmp/kisstnc` symlink.

An `ExecStartPost` runs after Direwolf has started.  It waits for the
`/tmp/kisstnc` link to show up, and then it copies that into
`/run/direwolf/<instancename>`.  If I run both of the above `systemctl
start ...` commands, I would end up with `/run/direwolf/uhf` and
`/run/direwolf/vhf`.

I've created a companion `kisstnc@.service` unit that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Requires=direwolf@%i.service
After=direwolf@%i.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/kissattach /run/direwolf/%i %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With this in place, I can simply run `systemctl start kisstnc@uhf` and
then:

- Systemd will start the `direwolf@uhf` service, because the
  `kisstnc@uhf` service `Requires` it to run first.
- The `direwolf@uhf` unit creates the `/run/direwolf/uhf` symlink
- The `kisstnc@uhf` unit runs the appropriate `kissattach` command

For this to work, your `/etc/ax25/axports` file must have port names
that match the instance names you're using in the above commands.  For
example, something like:

```
uhf     TEST-0      0   128 2   Direwolf@radio0
vhf     TEST-1      0   128 2   Direwolf@radio1
```